# jQuery - ajax return unknown numbers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have problem with ajax results when trying to search some id for example: 0205P, 04066H etc, it give me result correctly but when I click it, in input is some other number like 616, 7,13... So everything working perfect except when my search starting with 0 (zero).
My ID in database(MYSQL) is Varchar(8).
Here is my code:

dob.php

```
<input type="text" name="konto1" id="konto" class="form-control konto" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['konto1'])) echo $_POST['konto1']; ?><?php if(isset($_GET['konto1'])) echo $_GET['konto1'];?>" />  
                          <div class="boja"><div style="margin-top: 0px" id="selectKonto" class="list-group"></div></div>

<script>
                    // ajax call
                    $('#konto').keyup(function() {
                        var konto = $(this).val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'konto.php',
                            data: {
                                search: konto
                            },
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $('#konto').css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
                            },

                            success: function(data) {
                                if (!data.error) {
                                   // var reply = data.replace(/\s+/, ""); 
                                    $('#selectKonto').show();
                                    $('#selectKonto').html(data);

                                    $("#konto").css("background", "#FFF");

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    function selectKonto(val) {
                $("#konto1").text(val);
                $("#selectKonto").hide();

            } 
</script>
```

konto.php

```
if(!empty($konto)) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM konto WHERE ... LIMIT 10";
    $result = $db->query($q);

    if(!$result){
        die('QUERY FAILED' . $db->error);
    }
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo '<div><font size="2em"><a href="#" class="list-group-item konto" style="width: 555px;border: 1px solid grey;"
                onclick="selectKonto(\''.trim($row['kp_sif']).'\')">...
 <script>
    $('.konto').click(function() {     
    var text = $(this).html();
    $('.ime-konto').html(text);
    $("#selectKonto").hide();
    });
</script>
```

P.S. Field type in database must stay varchar, I can not change it to INT.

Comment: So is the leading zero making it to the server? Need to figure out where it is being dropped, on the clientside or the serverside.

Comment: *when I click it, in input is some other number like 616, 7,13... So* not much clear

Comment: have you tried with `var text = $(this).text(); $('.ime-konto').text(text);` in konto.php? Also, i don't see any element with class `ime-konto`, but it should be in your code i guess. Note: NEVER display POST or GET variables like this before having filtered dangerous values.

Comment: @JYoThI When I select the result, as you can see it at jQuery, selected result must give me 'kp_sif' from database. But it give me random numbers...

Comment: @Kaddath I try your change, but still the same one.

Comment: @epascarello I have checked inspect element before click and after click on result, as I can see onclick=selectKonto(number I have choosen) is good..After click giving me unknown number at input :/

Comment: Is it `onclick=selectKonto("0123")` or `onclick=selectKonto(0123)`

Comment: @epascarello `onclick="selectKonto(0103    )"`

Comment: well than the browser sees that as a number and removes the zero. but your php shows it has `'` around it...

Comment: @epascarello Is it possible to change as string? How can I handle with that?

Comment: @proofzy yes, javascript conversion can understand in an unexpected way numbers beginning by 0.. you really need the `'` here

Comment: @Kaddath so I should use https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: @proofzy you should rather get to have the `'` around your values in the generated javascript code.. which is strange because you escaped them properly. Beware that you should escape them in the script tag too (for the class selections)

Comment: @Kaddath I can't get  '  around my values, can you help me please?

Comment: @proofzy it is puzzling a bit, i reproduced the base of your code and it works fine here. Can you paste the exact ajax response you get? (depends on the browser you are using, in firefox you open the console, go to the network tab, in the list you should have your requested php file with a `xhr` status, click on it, and on the right you have a "response" tab with the exact text returned by the ajax call)

Comment: @Kaddath I really don't know what I have done, but its working now and return numbers with letters.  
Results are now onclick="selectKonto('0001G'). Thanks for your time mate!

Comment: @proofzy no problem, good luck for the rest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it works fine with quotes in php.

```
onclick="selectKonto(\''.trim($row['kp_sif']).'\')">
```

Obviously I had other problem in syntax.